xrandr commands not working in Ubuntu LTS 24.04
i just installed Ubuntu LTS 24.04 on my Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga. the issue is that the screen does not rotate when i rotate the monitor, it does on windows but not on ubuntu.
this is my graphics card:
Intel HD Graphics 620
now when i run monitor-sensor it does pick up the screen orientation even though the screen itself doesn't rotate:
    Waiting for iio-sensor-proxy to appear
+++ iio-sensor-proxy appeared
=== Has accelerometer (orientation: normal)
=== No ambient light sensor
=== No proximity sensor
    Accelerometer orientation changed: left-up
    Accelerometer orientation changed: right-up
    Accelerometer orientation changed: bottom-up
    Accelerometer orientation changed: normal

that's when i tried rotating the screen manually using xrandr and it didn't work, not only that but every xrandr command doesn't work, anything i try returns this whether it's rotate or mode or anything else:
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  23


Are you running Wayland?

xrandr was designed for X or X11 but now the Ubuntu default is Wayland. I think some xrandr commands will work under Wayland. Have a read up on the two and how they differ, or you can switch back to X11, see this article which shows how to choose by clicking the cog icon when you login. It's not obvious: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop
